# Very simple Android Event Reminder

Tags: android

I am looking for a simple Android App that allows me to enter an event on a certain date. No syncing, no internet usage. When run, the app will then only list upcoming events in order of date. Past events will be either ignored or deleted. Preferably free but I am not adverse to a small once-off fee. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for the calendar?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I only want events listed and not intervening days without events. I am unable to get calendar to do this.

Comment: That's called "Agenda View". Several Android calendar apps offer that at least via widgets.

Comment: Agenda View appears absent from my current version of Google Calender(ver 6.0.a.0.15).I have looked at some other calenders with Agenda View". Output is very cluttered with days without events. I haven't investigated widgets yet. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry to read that! Was just an idea I hoped turning out better.